# How to connect Jmeter to Redshift Database

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc, jmeter, amazon-redshift

Hello I would like to seek your assistance because I'm having difficulties to connect my Jmeter to our Redshift Database. Your response would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Steps I did

-Download Redshift jar file on this website

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/jdbc20-download-driver.html and copied on Jmeter Libraries

-Open Jmeter and Add JDBC Configuration

-Input Database URL, JDBC Driver Class, Username and Password

-Add JDBC Request (Insert SQL Query)

-Run Jmeter

-Error Occured

[Error Upon running Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bMrw.png)

**Example Parameter only**

Database URL: jdbc:redshift://redshift-db.**company**.com/**company**

JDBC Driver Class: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver

Username:

Password:

Screenshot:

[Downloaded Jar File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Xku.png)

[Jmeter Library Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW2vP.png)

[JDBC Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkXIN.png)

[Database Test Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WCrW.png)

[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP8GJ.png)

I tried to use these 3 JDBC Driver Class parameter however no luck from my side.

-com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver

-com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.DataSource

-com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [How to Test MySQL Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-test-connection) article

> 5. Fill in the Variable Name field. The value of this field is used to associate a specific connection configuration (JDBC Connection Configuration) to the database and a specific request (JDBC Request) sent by JMeter.
>
> If the field isn’t filled, the request won’t be sent and the JMeter Console would show the following message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Variable Name must not be empty for element:JDBC Connection Configuration. This can be seen in the screenshot below:

So you're almost there, all you need to do is to just populate "Variable Name for created pool" field in the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration):

[image]

and enter the same value in the [JDBC Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

[image]

Comment: i have tried same steps but im getting below error
java.lang.Noclassdeffounderror: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials